# I'm using SmartyAd SDK and getting error project not building

Tags: android, sdk, smarty, mobfox

I'm using this library:-

```
 implementation('com.smartyads:ad-container:0.4.7', {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
    transitive = true
})
```

I have used this SDK and it's giving me error like:-

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.github.mobfox:MobFox-Android-SDK-Core:3.2.7d.
```

Show Details

```
Affected Modules: app
```

not a single solution I found which can help me to fix this error. Project is not building giving me this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just because of SDK as they haven't fixed the issue with a new version.